# No sound on toshiba chromebook?

Tags: sound, lubuntu, chromebook, speakers, toshiba

I am currently using a toshiba cb30-b-104 with lubuntu 20.04 and it makes no sound. How can I get it to work?

Comment: installed chromebook? i made a procedure where I had to open the chromebook to unblock it, and only then I installed the a new bios and then lubuntu

Comment: Oops, I meant, how you installed Ubuntu on the Chromebook. Is it running bare metal or is it some kind of emulation, like crouton? Did you check if any additional drivers are available?

Comment: no emulation. It is Lubuntu and it is the only OS on the chromebook

Comment: I just need someone to tell me how to understand what the problem is, and then to help me to solve it. the problem is that it makes sound if I connect it to a bluetooth speaker, but zero sound if I use the chromebook built-in speakers

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/a/1469281/124466